# discord.py ошибка

Tags: python, discord, бот

Изначально у меня не работали команды при on_message, я вписал в конец функции await bot.process_commands(message) но при этом программа просто вылетает, не знаю что делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код надо прилагать текстом, а не скриншотом. Приложите также стректрейс ошибки.

Comment: Программа закрывается сразу после открытия